# Send email inside our SharePoint provider hosted add-in (remote event receiver)

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, provider-hosted-app, remote-event-receiver, send-email

I am working on a remote event receiver for our SharePoint online site collection, the remote event receiver is implemented as a provider hosted app hosted inside Azure WebApp. now inside the remote event receiver i want to send emails, but i am not sure how i can do so? in the server-side event receivers i use to use the .net `MailMessage`, but in the remote event receiver what i need to use?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` class and just supply your outbound SMTP configuration.

How you configure your SMTP service is out of scope of this network, though. If you don't have an available SMTP service/server, you may want to post over at ServerFault.

Comment: can you please provide more info on what i need to supply?

Comment: What specific questions did you have about the function (this should be posted over at StackOverflow for usage...)?